# How to deal with a great numbers of variables in C#

Tags: c#, variables

I'm making a game about genetics, and I stumble into a little "problem". (it's more of a question in fact)

I have a DNA class with a lot of variables that stores the infos about each "creature" in the game.

```
public class DNA {
    float size;
    float speed;
    float drag;
    float eyeSize;
    int numberOfEyes;
    float color_r;
    [...]
}
```

Now let's imagine I want to average two DNAs.

I could do:

```
DNA AverageDNAs (DNA dna1, DNA dna2) {
    DNA newDNA = new DNA ();
    newDNA.size = (dna1.size+dna2.size)/2f;
    newDNA.speed = (dna1.speed+dna2.speed)/2f;
    [...]
}
```

But it seems pretty long, and every time I'm going to do some calculation, I'll need to rewrite every variable one by one.

So I made a function that stores all the variables (normalized between 0 and 1) into a list

```
public class DNA {
    public float size;
    public float speed;
    [...]
    private List<float> tempList;
    public List<float> ToList() {
        if (tempList == null) {
        tempList = new List<float>();
        toReturn.Add (size/sizemax);
        toReturn.Add (speed/speedmax);
        [...]
        }
        return tempList
    }
    public static ADN fromList(List<float> list) {
        ADN toReturn = new ADN();
        toReturn.size = list[0]*sizemax;
        [...]
    }
}
```

Now, I can do:

```
DNA AverageDNAs (DNA dna1, DNA dna2) {
    List<float> dnaList1 = dna1.ToList();
    List<float> dnaList2 = dna2.ToList();
    List<float> newDNA = new List<float>();
    for (int i = 0; i<dnaList1.Count; i++) {
        newDNA.Add ((dnaList1[i]+dnaList2[i])/2f);
    }
    return DNA.fromList(newDNA);
}
```

It's easier to implement new functions and calculations, but it's pretty heavy (partly due to Lists creation), and not very pretty (I guess ?).

I would not prefer using just a `List<float>` for the sake of readability.

I wanted to know if there's a better way to handle that kind of situations?

(Please pardon my poor english, as I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: How performance critical is all this?

Comment: I have a population of 100 "creatures" and most of the calculation happens in game, at the same time as mesh creation (which is heavy too). But it's not just a matter of performances! I'd just like to know if there's a better way I haven't thought of, just to improve my knowledge

Comment: OK so if I assum 100 creatures, 100 properties and 1 update per second, that's about right?

Comment: if all your properties are of `float` or same type for that matter, instead of creating different fields, store them in a dictionary as key value pairs.

Comment: Sounds perfect for asynchronous programming.

Comment: Can't you split your DNA entites into several entity parts? For example a class containing data about eyes, another for speed/velocity. Then each class could override operators. And it would be easier to manipulate. Having more than 5 variables/properties of basic type on a class is often a code smell.

Comment: @atlaste It's more like: 1 update/generation, +- 50 variables/creature

Comment: @Souk21 OK that shouldn't really be a problem I suppose. I've cooked up something for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're always applying the same operation to all, you could use a parameter to specify the operation to be performed:

```
public DNA Cross(DNA dna1, DNA dna2, Func<float, float, float> operation)
{
  var newDNA = new DNA();

  newDNA.size = operation(dna1.size, dna2.size);
  newDNA.speed = operation(dna1.speed, dna1.speed);
  // And all the rest
}
```

This allows you to reuse this method for a wide range of different operations - as long as they always operate on the same amount of fields:

```
// Average
(d1, d2) => (d1 + d2) / 2f
// Sum
(d1, d2) => d1 + d2
// Random
(d1, d2) => RandomBool() ? d1 : d2
```

etc.

If you do want to apply the operation more selectively, you could also expand the `Cross` method to take an enum specifying *which* fields exactly you want to update. And of course, you might want to add another `Func` (or `Action`, depending on how comfortable you are with mutating arguments) to update the rest in any way you want.

Comment: So that would mean I'd have to do: `Cross(dna1,dna2,averageDNA())`  and then a averageDNA function with two parameters?

Comment: @Souk21 Either you can type it in directly as `(d1, d2) => (d1 + d2) / 2f`, or you can use an explicit method - just use it *without* the parentheses, e.g. `Cross(dna1, dna2, averageDNA)`. And yes, `averageDNA` must be `float averageDNA(float d1, float d2)` (in `Func<...>`, the last type argument is the return type, and all the ones before are ordered arguments as usual).

Comment: Is `Cross` a _"special"_ keyword? I can't find anything on it in the MSDN docs

Comment: @Souk21 No, why would it? It's just a method. The point is in the `Func<>` argument - that allows you to pass another function as an argument.

Comment: @Souk21 - no, its just a method name here. You could call it whatever you want (`Join`, `Reproduce` etc)

Comment: @Jamiec Ok, so how is it possible to implictly call it just by using (d1,d2) ?

Comment: @Souk21 Ooooh, no, that's not what's going on. The sample anonymous methods are not *calls* to `Cross` - they're just the arguments to use for `operation`. So you'd call e.g. `Cross(dna1, dna2, (d1, d2) => d1 + d2)`. Try looking up "anonymous methods C#" or "lambda expressions C#" if you haven't ever worked with those.

Comment: @Luaan I think the main problem that I have with this approach is that you have to apply the same operation on all properties at once; I wonder if that's really going to happen in his game for most operations, although only Souk knows that I suppose. Since there are only a few dozen properties, it might be better to add an enum parameter to Func, that allow you to specialize which properties to update.

Comment: @atlaste It depends entirely on a lot of things Souk isn't telling us, of course. But even if he could only use this approach to split his 50-variables into three separate crossing methods, it would be worth it. It's also trivial to use this to apply *random* crossing for each of the fields, which is another interesting crossing method.

Comment: @atlaste Right now I'm using the ToList() method to compare two DNAs (to know _how much_ they differ), to apply a mutation to a random variable, and to cross two DNAs (I'm not averaging, it was just an example)

Comment: @atlaste for the crossing, `List<float>` is pretty useful, though, as I just have to pick crossover points, iterate the lists, and _"cut"_

Comment: @Souk21 Indeed. Though with a bit of cleverness, this can also be done with my solution - either pass field index as another argument (cleaner), or use a mutable variable in the anonymous method (generally frowned upon, but...), something like `int spliceIndex = RandomIndex(); Cross(dna1, dna2, (d1, d2) => spliceIndex-- >= 0 ? d1 : d2);`. You can use the same approach for any aggregations you might need (or better, write an `Aggregate` method to handle that).

Answer (score 4):

I think a better approach is to define your own arithmetic operators on the DNA class. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx) on how to do it.

```
public class DNA {
    float size;
    float speed;
    float drag;
    float eyeSize;
    int numberOfEyes;
    float color_r;
    [...]

   public static DNA operator +(DNA dna1, dna1 rhs) 
   {
       DNA newDNA = new DNA ();
       newDNA.size = (dna1.size+dna2.size);
       newDNA.speed = (dna1.speed+dna2.speed);
       [...]

       return newDNA;
   }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var newDna = dna1 + dna2;
```

I guess internally you can use @Luaan suggestion to avoid retyping the same thing over and over, but the usage is neater with the operators IMHO.

```
 public static DNA operator +(DNA dna1, dna1 rhs) 
 {
      return Cross(dna1, dna2, (d1, d2) => d1 + d2);  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! About your last suggestion, I don't see how to use both method

Comment: I updated the post. Essentially internally you can call @Luaan's `Cross` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dictionary instead of the fields. So that when you need to get the average you can use:

```
foreach(var item in this._dict)
{
    avgDNA._dict[item.Key] = (item.Value + other._dict[item.Key]) / 2;
}
```

That way you don't care about new fields.

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward indeed. Haven't thought about that, thanks! But it might be a little bit too costly.

Comment: Well, you **did** get some better solutions  :)

Answer (score 1):

You could define an interface/class model around a `Trait` which knows how to "combine" with a similar trait. For example, a trair represented as a float, where the combination is an average could be expressed as:

```
public class FloatTrait 
{
    private float val;
    public FloatTrait(float val)
    {
        this.val = val;
    }
    public float Value{get { return this.val; }}

    public FloatTrait CombineWith(FloatTrait t)
    {
       return new FloatTrait((this.Value + t.Value)/2.0f);
    }
}
```

You can then have properties in your `DNA` object which represent traits, not absolute values

```
public class DNA
{
    public FloatTrait Size{get;set;}
    public FloatTrait Speed{get;set;}
}
```

The addition of a dictionary to reference these makes it much simpler to combine them (Worth noting: Ive used string literals as the key, it would be more appropriate to use an enumeration! h/t @Luaan)

```
public class DNA
{
    private Dictionary<string, FloatTrait> traits = new Dictionary<string, FloatTrait>() {
        {"Size", new FloatTrait(5.0)},
        {"Speed", new FloatTrait(50.0)},
    }

    public DNA(Dictionary<string, FloatTrait> dict)
    {
        this.traits = dict;
    }

    public FloatTrait this[string key]{ get{ return traits[key]; } }

    public float Size{ get{ return traits["Size"].Value; }
    public float Speed{ get{ return traits["Speed"].Value; }

    public DNA CombineWith(DNA other)
    {
        var newDict = this.traits.ToDictionary(k => k.Key
                                               v => v.Value.CombineWith(other[v.Key]));
        return new DNA(newDict);
    }
}
```

You could extend this to support "traits" other than those represented by a `float`. You could also alter the mechanism for "combining" traits if averaging is not appropriate.

Live example of this working: http://rextester.com/MVH5197

Comment: You already use string constants, why not just use enums instead?

Comment: interesting approach, thanks! But `Dictionary` seems a bit costly in my case.

Comment: @Souk21 - costly how? Its lookups are quick and its footprint is minimal.

Comment: Maybe I'm under this impression because I always use `TryGetValue` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here you're not always doing the same operation, and the operation depends on the type of object.

First thing to do is to add an extra abstraction layer to `float`'s that defines the base functionality. I assume you want to add semantics, e.g.:

```
public interface IDNAComputable
{
    IDNAComputable Grow(float length);
    // etc.
}
```

If you end up with most methods being 'empty', make it an abstract class and define some base implementation that does nothing.

Next, add a class that wraps a float, int, string or whatever you like. You might want to make semantic classes like weight, height, etc like I did. In this case I use a struct, but if you cram a lot of stuff in there you might want to use a class. The main thing here is that they all share the same interface that we can use to do stuff:

```
public struct Height : IDNAComputable
{
    // implement members
}
```

*Updated* It seems that you want to cut things and so on as well. Might want to add an extra enum that describes the properties. Since they map to integers, you can do a lot of fun stuff with them, including random indexes, etc.

```
public enum DNAProperty : int
{
    BodyWidth,
    BodyHeight,
    MouthWidth,
    MouthHeight,
    // ...
}
```

Last thing to do is build the DNA thing itself:

```
public class DNA
{
    private Width bodyWidth;
    private Height bodyHeight;
    private Width mouthWidth;
    private Height mouthHeight;
    // etc.

    public void Update(Func<IDNAComputable, IDNAComputable, DNAProperty> op)
    {
        bodyHeight = (Height)op(bodyHeight, DNAProperty.BodyHeight);
        bodyWidth = (Width)op(bodyWidth, DNAProperty.BodyWidth);
        // etc for all other stuff.
    }

    public void Merge(Func<IDNAComputable, IDNAComputable, IDNAComputable, DNAProperty> op, DNA otherCreature)
    {
        bodyHeight = (Height)op(bodyHeight, otherCreature.bodyHeight, DNAProperty.BodyHeight);
        bodyWidth = (Width)op(bodyWidth, otherCreature.bodyWidth, DNAProperty.BodyWidth);
        // etc for all other stuff.
    }
}
```

Note that the overhead is not that bad, it basically uses a few extra indications and virtual function calls; it should be fast enough for your use case.

Last thing to do is to define the actual functionality.

```
public void GrowCreature(DNA creature, float height) 
{
   creature.Update((a)=>a.Grow(height));
}
```

*update* Some practical examples based on your comments:

> Right now I'm using the ToList() method to compare two DNAs (to know how much they differ), to apply a mutation to a random variable, and to cross two DNAs (I'm not averaging, it was just an example)

Calculate the difference is easy with this approach, even if your 'height' doesn't attribute the same as the 'width'. You can even introduce a 'body mass' property if you like etc:

```
double diff = 0;
creature.Merge((lhs, rhs, prop) => { diff += lhs.Difference(rhs); return lhs; });
```

... or if you only want to use a certain set of properties for that, you can do that as well:

```
double diff = 0;
creature.Merge((lhs, rhs, prop) => 
    { 
        if (prop == DNAProperty.BodyMass)
        {
            diff += lhs.Difference(rhs); 
        } 
    return lhs; });
```

> List is pretty useful, though, as I just have to pick crossover points, iterate the lists, and "cut"

Don't need a list for that:

```
double diff = 0;
creature.Merge((lhs, rhs, prop) => 
    { 
        diff += lhs.Difference(rhs); 

        if (diff > SomeCutThreshold) { return lhs; }
        else { return rhs; }
    });
```

... or perhaps you do want to know where the cut point will be?

> cut points meant: `for(int i=0; i<dna1.count;i++) { newList[i] = i>cutPoint? dna1[i] : dna2[i] }`

```
double diff = 0;
DNAProperty cutpoint = (DNAProperty)int.MaxValue;
creature.Merge((lhs, rhs, prop) => 
    { 
        diff += lhs.Difference(rhs); 

        if (diff > SomeCutThreshold) { cutpoint = prop; diff = double.MinValue; }
        return lhs;
    });

creature.Merge((lhs, rhs, prop) => ((int)prop > (int)cutpoint)?lhs:rhs);
```

**To conclude**

While this might seem like more work, if you make the right abstractions and inheritance trees you should end up with less code, not more. For example, most basic functionality between 'Height' and 'Width' is probably shared. I'd also try to end up with 1 or 2 overloads of the 'Func' thing, no more.

Comment: You might run into problems with `operator` being a reserved word.

Comment: cut points meant: `for(int i=0; i<dna1.count;i++) { 
newList[i] = i>cutPoint? dna1[i] : dna2[i]
}`

Comment: @Souk21 well, that's basically what it does, right?

Comment: If I understand all your code (and to be honest, I'm not sure), it's more or less the same suggestion as Luaan but with one more layer of abstraction ? Sorry if I'm mistaking.

Comment: @Souk21 The level of abstraction is to ensure all properties share the same base type, so you have a common interface. The func part is more or less the same; that's actually a standard solution for this family of problems, called a *strategy pattern*. However, to make this work in c# you need to have same (base) type, hence the level of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use reflection to get the properties, then loop through them on your list of objects?

In case you're not familiar with reflection, here's an MSDN example that should help:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx